# How to easily make protected variable in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, private, protected

I use this to get data from some site:

```
const key = 'secret_key';

router.get('/get', (req, res) => {
  axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      'Key': key,
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response)
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error))
});
```

When there is an error, `key` is visible to users. I would like to use protected or private, but I can't. In other questions, there are long complicated functions to make the variable protected. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "visible to users"? Anyone can open devtools and see any data in your code. The only thing you could do is scramble your code to make it very difficult to read, but it will not hide the data. You can only "protect" your variables from other scripts that executed on the same page, not the user.

Comment: @vanowm is there any other way to make it invisible? Or only this? If it were private or protected variable, wouldn't it change anything?

Comment: No, not really, the user still can add a break point in the devtool where the variable is used and see the content of that variable.

Comment: @Weronika This looks like NodeJS. Is it? If so, then please tag the question as such. (In that case, the value wont be visible through a browsers DevTools.)

Comment: @Ivar yes, it's node.js. What do you mean with in that case, the value wont be visible through a browsers DevTools?

Comment: @Weronika I'm referring to vanowm's comments. All code/html/javascript that is sent to the user's browser is accessible for that user and can be viewed/altered. JavaScript that runs on a NodeJS server is executed on the server and is not sent to the user's browser. As such users wont be able to this value (unless there is an error like you say).

Comment: @Ivar So if I change error handling from `error => res.status(500).send(error)` to `res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error")` . It will be ok and this key won't be visible?

Comment: @Weronika I'm not familiar enough with NodeJS to guarantee anything so don't take my word for it, but that does make sense. `.send(error)` likely sends the error to the user and as such they are able to see exactly what is going wrong. That kind of information is useful for developers, but you don't want to tell the outside world more than they need to know. (Usually you want to write some information to log files so you can access this information later, but I'm not sure how that works in NodeJS.

Comment: @Ivar I understand and thank you for your answer. Now I know what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by another way thanks to @Ivar.

Before:

```
 .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error))
```

After:

```
 .catch(error => res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error"))
```